# Where I can found any manuals about how does http://jenkins.ros.org/ is working/configured/generating jobs

Tags: jenkins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I am interested in continuous integration technologies and especially Jenkins. At http://jenkins.ros.org/ I saw very complicated but yet functional, fast and reliable example of continuous integration system.

Could you please provide links to the repository where http://jenkins.ros.org/ configuration/templates/scripts are stored, or any other materials which describes technologies used for generating http://jenkins.ros.org/ instance (jobs, views, plugins, server config)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240278/where-i-can-found-any-manuals-about-how-does-http://jenkins.ros.org/-is-working/configured/generating-jobs/) by [Mark.Zaslavskiy](https://answers.ros.org/users/27595/mark.zaslavskiy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The wiki page http://wiki.ros.org/buildfarm contains a brief description and will reference additional resources as well as the repositories involved.

Btw. the domain http://jenkins.ros.org is not the canonical URL. It was referring to the old build server and is only showing the content of the following (it is supposed to redirect you which doesn't work at the moment). The actual domain name you should use is http://build.ros.org

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2016-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mark.Zaslavskiy](https://answers.ros.org/users/27595/mark.zaslavskiy/) on 2016-07-27**:
Thanks a lot! It is exactly what I want!